# I don't understand this Error called "Buffer Overflow"

Tags: c

I am learning C, it's my first programming language. I don't understand this Error called "Buffer Overflow". My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char a[5];
gets(a);
printf ("%s",a);
return 0;
}
```

Now when I type more that 5 words it should end with five, shouldn't it? But its showing some buffer error and I have no idea what to do about it. please help me with this.
isn't that `a[5]` is the word limit of 5?

I'm very confused.
Sorry if it distrub you all and thanks in advance.

Comment: *"more that 5 words"* - words?? If you type more then four *characters*, including the newline (so three characters and your keyboard enter-key), this overflows. Don't use `gets`, it's vile, evil, and so dangerous it was *removed* from the standard library now-seven years ago.

Comment: USING CAPITALS IS CONSIDERED __SHOUTING__. Please don't do that.

Comment: `gets` gets whatever is in the input. It does not limit to the size of the buffer.

Comment: You should know that all capital text is conidered as rude.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the limit is 4 characters, because a null terminator will be added to the end in order to form a valid string. This means that you need `char a[6]` if you want space for 5 characters.

Also, `gets` shouldn't be used for this exact reason. Instead, I would use `scanf`:

```
scanf("%5s", a);
```

This will tell it to read 5 characters at most, even if there are more.

With those changes, the program should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a[6];
    scanf("%5s", a);
    printf ("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

It's also possible to use `fgets` instead:

```
fgets(a, 5, stdin);
```

Comment: thank you. now i understand that and will do as same as you saw me. but one question?? is this get() function dangerous every one is saying no to this function???

Comment: No problem! Yes, `gets` it is indeed dangerous and should not be used anymore. `scanf` can do the same things, but is safer.

Comment: Why not `fgets` ?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that. Added it to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: NOW WHAT IS THIS FGETS???so hard for to get this gets() to scanf and i m hearing this fgets and puts()????? which is simple and effective with no buffer

Comment: You can use either `fgets` or `scanf`, just don't use `gets`.

Comment: why so many function to perform the similar task. does'nt it makes programming hard???

Comment: Mostly historical reasons. C is 46 years old, so in the meantime lots of stuff happened that raised a need for improved versions of old functions.

Comment: @VivekTamang: `fgets()` reads a sequence of `char`. `scanf()` does formatted input. It for example could read an `int`, a `float` and a "string" in one go. It is more mighty, so it's more difficult to use. I recommend to read the function's documentation. Trying to learn C by trial&error is known to cause depressions. Do not do this.